# How to sync jquery sortable lists that contain cloned elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've a peculiar situation. I have two lists. 1 list contains all items, and 2 contains top list. Obviously items overlap, and items in the second list are marked with class clone-23 clone-25 according to which element from list 1 are they cloned from.

```
Example:
List 1
1 run
2 eat
3 drink
4 play

List 2 (TOP)
1 run (class clone)
2 eat (class clone)
```

When re-arranged data is saved to DB.

I would like to avoid refresh and re-pulling of data from DB. So I would like to sync position of elements in two lists.
So whenever user drags around item in list 1, list 2 automatically shows changed positions and vice versa.

I initiate my sortable:

```
// Initiate jquery ui sortable
    $(".word-list").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        cursor: 'move',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        connectWith: 'ol.word-list',
        //containment: "body",
        // 
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // Starting position of the word element
            //ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
            //console.dir(ui.item.startPos);
        },
        //
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            //
            save_word_order(this);
            //
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
```

Clone element html:

```
<li data-con-id="94" data-order-id="1" data-note="" class="ui-state-default clone-94"</li>
```

Lists are simply:

```
<ol id="tabs-1" class="word-list"></ol>
<ol id="tabs-2" class="word-list"></ol>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please clear your question further, i can help then

Comment: @Shaheer I tried... still not clear?

Comment: can you provide the fidle

Comment: How does "class clone" in list 2 relate to the items in list 1? I can see that "1 run" exists in both list, but your use of "class clone" need clarification.

Comment: Does list two always show the top two items from list one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this fiddle for code which syncs the order of items common to both lists:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/22jc2/

Note that in my example I have simplified list two's li elements by not including the clone attributes; instead I am comparing items in both list by the list item's innerText value. It should be fairly easy for you to refactor my solution to use the clone item attributes if you really need to use them.

The script which I've used to achieve the synchronisation of the order of the common list items is:

```
var reorderLists = function (list1, list2) {
    $('#' + list1 + ' li').each(function (index) {
        var sortableItemWithText = $('#' + list2 + ' li:contains(' + this.textContent + ')');
        if (sortableItemWithText.length === 1) {
            sortableItemWithText.appendTo('#' + list2);
            return;
        }
    });
};

$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var parentNodeId = ui.item[0].parentNode.id;
        if (parentNodeId == "sortable1") {
            reorderLists("sortable1", "sortable2");
        }

        if (parentNodeId == "sortable2") {
            reorderLists("sortable2", "sortable1");
        }
    }
});

$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Note that the syncing of the order of common list items works if you change the position of items in either list 1 or list 2.

Also note that by commenting out:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

You'll be able to see the lists updating automatically when you move the list items; this makes it easier to confirm that the re-order routine is work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help :

> See this fiddle for code which syncs the order of items common to both
>   lists:

http://jsfiddle.net/penjepitkertasku/6bk7B/1/

```
$(function() {
var dragElementID = "";
var dropElementID = "";
var dragElementItemName = "";
var allElementItemName = "";

    $(".word-list").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        //revert: 'invalid',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        connectWith: 'ol.word-list',
        start: function(e, ui){
            var id = $('ol.word-list').children().index($(ui.item[0]));
            var name = $('ol.word-list').children(':eq(' + id + ')').text();

            dragElementItemName = name;
            dragElementID = this.id;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var id = $('ol.word-list').children().index($(ui.item[0]));

            //validate
            if(dragElementID == dropElementID) { return; }
            if(id == -1)return;
            if(dragElementID == "tabs-1")
            {
                if(allElementItemName.indexOf(dragElementItemName,1) > 0) { $(this).sortable('cancel'); return; }
                var elm = $(ui.item[0]).clone(true).removeClass('box ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('box-clone');
                $('ol.word-list').children(':eq(' + id + ')').after(elm);
                $(this).sortable('cancel');

            }else{
                ui.item.remove(); 
            }
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            //
            //save_word_order(this);
            //
        },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            //
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            //
            dropElementID = this.id;
            allElementItemName = '|' + $('#' + dropElementID + ' li').text() + '|';
        },
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
});
```